# Any compact solution for $dX/dt = A X(t) + X(t) A^T$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $X(t) \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$, where $X(t)^T = X(t)$ (i.e., it is symmetric for each $t$), is there any compact solution for the following linear differential equation?

$$\frac{dX(t)}{dt} = A X(t) + X(t) A^T,$$

where $A \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$.

Thanks!

PS: In this question, "Compact" means the solution can be expressed by a function or a integral of $A$, $X(0)$, and $t$ (dummy variables are permitted), e.g., for the following linear ode

$$\frac{dX(t)}{dt} = A X(t) + B,$$

the compact solution is

$$X(t) = e^{At} X(0) + \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)} B d\tau$$.

Comment: Compact in what sense?

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks very much for your comments, and I have give a brief illustration correspondingly :-)

Comment: Ok. It is called a [*closed form solution*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closed-FormSolution.html).

Comment: @A.Γ. Awesome! Much better than I thought! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce $\Phi(t)=e^{-At}X(t)e^{-A^Tt}$ and differentiate it using $\frac{d}{dt}e^{At}=Ae^{At}=e^{At}A$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(t)=\dot\Phi(t)=e^{-At}[\underbrace{-AX(t)+\dot X(t)-X(t)A^T}_{=0}]e^{-A^Tt}=0.
$$
Hence $\Phi(t)$ is a constant matrix. Setting $t=0$ gives
$$
\Phi(t)=\Phi(0)=X(0)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \color{red}{X(t)=e^{At}X(0)e^{A^Tt}}.
$$

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot! [+1]

Comment: All of your solutions I see are very clear. Very helpful.

Comment: @JeffFaraci Thank you for the support.